# Convert var to class type of ClassTracker IQueryable

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, iqueryable

```
var q = from n in CS.trackers
group n by n.Id into g
select g.OrderByDescending(t => t.DateTime).Take(1);
```

Above code gives the desired result which fetches me the latest record of `Id` according to the datetime. But when I try to convert it to a `class` for it to convert in a `IQueryAble`.

```
List<ClassTracker> o = (from h in q
select new ClassTracker{
Id = 
}
)
```

when i do Id = q. I dont get the q.Id. I want to convert it to a type of ClassTracker so that I can use .AsQueryAble to convert it to `IQueryable<ClassTracker>`

Answer (score 0):

You are not getting `Id = q` in your second query because your first query is not returing an `IEnumerable<T>` instead it is returning `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>>` so in your second query you will have to do `SelectMany` like this:-

```
List<ClassTracker> o = (from h in q
                        from t in h
                        select new ClassTracker
                                              {
                                                  Id = t.Id,
                                                  //Other properties here
                                              }
                       ).ToList();
```

But for me you can do all this in a single query like this:-

```
IQueryable<ClassTracker> result = (from n in CS.trackers
                     group n by n.Id into g
                     let firstObj = g.OrderByDescending(t => t.DateTime).First()
                     select new ClassTracker
                     {
                         Id = firstObj .Id,
                         //Other properties here
                     }).AsQueryable<ClassTracker>();
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply rahul. I am getting an error as follows.

base = {"The method 'First' can only be used as a final query operation. Consider using the method 'FirstOrDefault' in this instance instead."}

Comment: the error is solved. But I am not getting the latest record. I mean the record which is twice in data base with different dates. Both the records is appearing. I only want the data(single row) of the latest date

Comment: the error is solved. But I am not getting the latest record. I mean the record which is twice in data base with different dates. Both the records is appearing. I only want the data(single row) of the latest date

Comment: @user2998990 - Okay you are using the first approach or second approach? It should return just 1 row if you are using `FirstOrDefault`.

Comment: I am using 2nd approach. exactly as u said. Can you check it using FirstOrDefault.?

Comment: @user2998990 - Okay try removing the `AsQueryable` and simply put `var` and check if you are getting correct result.

Comment: @user2998990 - Really weird. For each Id it must be returning 1 record, I hope this is what you want. Otherwise please show me some sample input and output you are expecting.